# Is there any preferred way of login on non-webview clients

Tags: facebook, rest, authentication, legacy

I have a smart TV app, that can not use the outh login method. Is it OK to use Legacy REST APIs for login? Is there any other preferred way? How long will the Legacy REST APIs be supported?

Comment: Facebook has not announced the end-date for the REST API, but they have made it clear that it is unwise to develop further on it. Perhaps you can have them login to Facebook via a mobile app or website, and then connect their account on that Smart TV App with the session on that device/website